# Make basic cipher function more readable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this basic cipher function:

```
def encrypt_decrypt(data, in_or_out):
    pass_lst = list(data)
    return_list = []

    if in_or_out == "in":
        for i in pass_lst:
            num = ord(i) + 10
            return_list.append(chr(num))
    else:
        for i in pass_lst:
            num = ord(i) - 10
            return_list.append(chr(num))

    return ''.join(return_list)
```

I want to make this cipher a little more readable and a little `DRY`er.. Is there a way I can shorten this function successfully?

Comment: use list comprehensions like this: `return_list = [chr(ord(i) + 10) for i in pass_lst]` for example. This way you don't have to initialize\declare the lists too. This whole function can be condensed in 4-5 lines

Comment: Don't write one function that does two completely different (and in this case opposite) things based on the value of a parameter. Write two functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` instead.

Comment: Actually it condenses to a single line if you consider this: `return ''.join([chr(ord(i) + 10) if in_or_out == 'in' else chr(ord(i) - 10) for i in list(data)])` readable. I do.

Comment: @chepner But writing multiple functions that will basically do the same thing, and basically achieve the same concept, is kind of repetitive isn't it?

Comment: But is it a good idea to compress the function to a single line? We need to write code to be easily understandable to the next developer. Easily understandable is also easier to get correct and maintain. Clarity is #1.

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin The goal is to write readable, maintainable code, not to compress it to its smallest possible form. Not all repetition is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca make it DRYer by computing the ±10 from the `in_or_out` parameter. Eg,

```
def encrypt_decrypt(data, in_or_out):
    delta = {'in': 10, 'out': -10}[in_or_out]
    return_list = []
    for i in list(data):
        num = ord(i) + delta
        return_list.append(chr(num))
    return ''.join(return_list)
```

And that can be made more compact by using a list comprehension:

```
def encrypt_decrypt(data, in_or_out):
    delta = {'in': 10, 'out': -10}[in_or_out]
    return ''.join([chr(ord(i) + delta) for i in data])
```

Notice that I'm directly iterating over `data`. That will work if `data` is a string, list or tuple.

However, you should be aware that your code isn't safe: it doesn't handle char codes where `ord(i) + delta` is outside the 0-255 range.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, functions should do *one* thing; combining two functions into one, then using an argument to trigger which "embedded" function actually runs, is a bit of an antipattern. You can still abstract out the common code (here, following PM 2Ring's definition):

```
def encrypt(data):
    return _modify(data, 10)

def decrypt(data):
    return _modify(data, -10)

def _modify(data, delta):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(i) + delta) for i in data])
```

In general, your pair of functions is not going to be this symmetrical, though, and it will not be so easy to implement both in terms of one clear function. In that case, you *definitely* do not want to be stuffing both implementations into one `encrypt_or_decrypt` function.

(Even if you *do* combine them, don't use two separate sets of terms. Pick one of "encrypt"/"decrypt" or "in"/"out" and stick with it for both the function name and the value to pass to the argument.)

If you really need to choose between encrypting and decrypting based on the value of a parameter, store your two functions in a dictionary:

```
d = {"encrypt": encrypt, "decrypt": decrypt}

d[in_or_out](value)
```